# wkhtmltopdf writes in apache error log for every pdf created

Tags: php, apache, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, error-log

Every time a PDF is created in WKHTMLTOPDF (using php) i am getting the following in the apache error log:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
[==========>                                                 ] 17%
[===================>                                        ] 32%
[==============================>                             ] 50%
[=====================================>                      ] 63%
[============================================>               ] 74%
[============================================================] 100%
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
[============================================================] Object 1 of 1
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ] Preparing
[============================================================] Page 1 of 1
Done
```

However the pdf is created without any errors, is there a way of stopping this as the error logs are getting very large and also masking genuine errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To silence wkhtmltopdf specifically:

1. Use the `--quiet` flag:

   ```
    exec("wkhtmltoimage -q …");
   ```
2. And redirect **stderr** per `2>/dev/null` or similar shell features:

   ```
    exec("wkhtmltopdf -q … 2>&1");
   ```

The latter works with most command-line tools, btw.

Comment: Confirmed. The '-q' flag does indeed silence the log. The documentation says to use `--log-level error` but that creates an exception.