# How do I disable notice log entries on wkhtmltopdf?

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

## The Setup

I have a LAMP stack site that uses wkhtmltopdf to convert several html templates to pdf on demand by the customer. This is working fine.

Version: wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 (with patched qt)
CentOS 6

## The Problem

I occasionally review my error log to make sure the system is working and to debug errors that happen on the live server. However my log is filled with entries from wkhtmltopdf that look like this:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

I'm using the command like: `wkhtmltopdf /temp/source/file.html`

## My Attempt

According to the [documentation](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) I can turn this off with the direction `--log-level error`. However If I include this the entire command fails.

## The question

How do I turn off these notices to stop cluttering my log (nearly 80% of my log)? Was the command renamed and the documentation not updated? Is theri a different way to capture command line log entries and prevent them from writing to the log or redirect to a different log that I can cron scrape?

Comment: Have you tried with `--log-level none` or `--quiet` (should be equivalent)? WickedPdf uses `-q` (the short version of `--quiet`) without issue. If there's an error, you'll generally be able to tell by not having an output pdf.

Comment: `-q` does indeed work. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wkhtmltopdf writes in apache error log for every pdf created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221196/wkhtmltopdf-writes-in-apache-error-log-for-every-pdf-created)